# Google Glass: Only one Looper may be created per thread

Tags: android, multithreading, bluetooth, textview, handler

Im trying to print the amount of bytes recieved over a bluetoothsocket. But im getting this error: ``Only one Looper may be created per thread'' -- cant find out what im doing wrong.

```
 public void listenForData()
{
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    final Message msg = new Message();
    final Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        final String bytes = msg.toString();
            text.setText(bytes);
            return false;
        }
    });

    Runnable leesRunnable = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run ()
        {          
            try
            {                  
                InputStream inStream = mBluetoothSocket.getInputStream();
                bytes = inStream.read(buffer);
                msg.arg1=bytes;
                handler.sendMessage(msg);
            }
            catch (IOException e1) 
            {}         
        }
    };
    Thread leesInputThread= new Thread(leesRunnable);
    leesInputThread.start();
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `listenForData()` from?

Comment: @Emmanuel listenForData() is called by the click of a button, from here: `public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`

Comment: Can you post the code for the class `listenForData()` resides?

Comment: Well, there is not much code left in that class, besided the `public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` from where the function is being called and of course some declarations.